# How to use a function from another file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm building a Node.js app, and it has a lot of functions and objects. So in order to make the code cleaner, I want to put them in separate files.

Here is an example.

`functions.js`

```
function compare(a,b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`index.js`

```
let a = 1;
let b = 1;
// i want to use that function here
console.log(compare(a,b));
```

How to do that ? And not only for function but objects and other variables.

Comment: You export and import functions or objects between modules in node.js. Frankly, there are hundreds of tutorials on this on the web and stack overflow isn't really a great tutorial resource, so I'd suggest you start with one of those tutorials and then come back here when you have an implementation and have a specific problem with that implementation that you want help with.  Please do some reading on  your own.  It's not hard and there are many full featured examples all over the web.  Any beginning tutorial on node.js will show this.

Comment: You may want to read [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24292207/697630)